# jQuery Toggle not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, function, toggle, slidetoggle, toggleclass

I have an issue with jQuery toggle not working in IE 8.  It works in **all** the other browsers as well as IE 9 and IE 10.  I'm also using Bootstrap with it.

Here's my sample code below.  Can someone point me in the right direction?
The fate of mankind rests on your answer.  :-)

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js">
    </script>


    <script>
       $(function() {
         $('#Hiring').click(function() {
             $('.Hiring').slideToggle('fast');
             $( "#HIR" ).toggleClass( "icon-chevron-down", 07 );
             return false;
           });

        });
    </script>



    <ul class="nav nav-list">
      <li><a href="#" id="Hiring"><i class="icon-chevron-right" id="HIR">
      </i> Hiring</a>

        <div class="Hiring" style="display:none;">
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
            </ul>                                         
        </div> 

      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [horse's mouth](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/03/01/jquery-2-0-beta-2-released/):

> Remember that jQuery 2.0 will not run on IE 6, 7, or **8**;